# Probability of x out of G objects sharing a bucket with the R randomly distributed other objects in n buckets?

Tags: combinatorics

If I have n buckets, and there are G green balls randomly put in those buckets, one at a time, and I put R red balls randomly, also one at a time, in those n buckets, what is the formula for the probability that x out of the G green balls share a bucket with a red ball?

See I'm really bad at probability, in my head it looks like it should be just nCr, 
(x/g)Choose(n)

But that doesn't work as it's not an integer most of the time.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Can you also lay out your effort as well? If you feel it's hard to start, take $n=2, G = 1, R = 1$, and gradually increase.

Comment: No I have absolutely no skill in probability beyond when to use factorial, when to use nCr, when to use powers, and what a normal distribution _looks_ like. It's by far my worst area of math knowledge wise AND thinking wise. Will the q get closed if I don't try something? Cos I suppose I can try write something, even if it's so, so, so wrong.

See with probability, there's no proofs, theres no way for me to see if I'm right like in algebbra

Comment: Forget about factorials and $^nC_r$ and all that. Just try a really, really simple case like the one gunes suggested by first principles/complete enumeration. The question - being essentially a routine textbook question - is likely to be closed as it stands. You should also specify some details more clearly: 1. By "putting ... balls randomly" do you mean each ball is placed at random *with equal probability on each bucket regardless of its current contents*? 2. By "share a bucket *with* ***a*** *red ball*" do you mean "with one or more red balls" or do you mean "with exactly one red ball"?